# Laravel and Backendless

Tags: mysql, laravel, backend, laravel-5, backendless

Everyone

I am developing an application of laravel that will run on mobile devices and web versions. Recently I've found backend service backendless. How can I use backendless service with the laravel?

Answer (score 1):

I never used Backendless but i think you should use [this](https://github.com/wolverine2k/Laravel-Backendless)